# Are dotnet 1.1.4 migration files no longer compatible with dotnet2 migrations?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

It seems like when I try to do a `dotnet ef migrations add <name>`, I get a huge migration file that seems to include everything from the beginning of my migrations since 1.1.4.

Are the snapshots from 1.1.4 not compatible with 2.0.0? Since its adding stuff from the very begininng, when I run `dotnet ef database update` it tries to remove and rename things that don't exist anymore which causes the update to fail.

I'm also getting this warning:

> The annotation 'TableName' was specified twice with potentially
>   different values. Specifying the same annotation multiple times for
>   different providers is no longer supported. Review the generated
>   Migration to ensure it is correct and, if necessary, edit the
>   Migration to fix any issues.

Comment: Okay, I removed it.